# Using Boost.Pool in VS2010 - Linker error

Tags: c++, boost

The [Boost.Pool documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/installation.html) says that (emphasis mine):

> **The Boost Pool library is a header-only library.** That means there is
>   no .lib, .dll, or .so to build; just add the Boost directory to your
>   compiler's include file path, and you should be good to go!

But when I try to compile code like this in VS2010 SP1:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost\pool\pool_alloc.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, 
        boost::pool_allocator<wchar_t>> PoolString;

    std::vector<PoolString> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        PoolString s(L"Some test string. ABCDEF.");
        vec.push_back(s);
    }

    // Release pool memory
    boost::singleton_pool<boost::pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(wchar_t)>::release_memory();

    return 0;
}
```

I got a linker error:

> error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib'

Is Boost.Pool documentation incorrect?
What am I missing here?
How can I use Boost.Pool?

Comment: The `boost::singleton_pool` is using a `mutex` type, which is located in the `boost::thread` library. Therefore you need to link libboost_thread.

Comment: if you look in boost\pool\detail\mutex.hpp it appears that pool lib defines its own mutex and does not refer the boost::thread lib

Comment: @MariusBucur: I'll check again, to verify my answer.

Comment: @nabulke Indeed boost::pool 1.49 uses the boost::thread, I was looking at version 1.47 which defines its own mutex (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/pool/detail/mutex.hpp). If linking with thread lib is not desired there is the option to use and older pool lib version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boost::singleton_pool` is using a default mutex implementation that is located in `boost::thread`, which is *not* header only.

See the [singleton_pool header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/pool/singleton_pool.hpp) quoted below for information on how to remove the dependency:

> **Mutex** This class is the type of mutex to use to protect
>   simultaneous access to the underlying Pool.   Can be any Boost.Thread
>   Mutex type or boost::details::pool::null_mutex.  It is
>   exposed so that users may declare some singleton pools normally (i.e.,
>   with synchronization), but   some singleton pools without
>   synchronization (by specifying
>   boost::details::pool::null_mutex) for efficiency reasons. 
>   The member typedef mutex exposes the value of this template
>   parameter.  The default for this  parameter is
>   boost::details::pool::default_mutex which is a synonym for either
>   boost::details::pool::null_mutex  (when threading support is
>   turned off in the compiler (so BOOST_HAS_THREADS is not set), or
>   threading support  has ben explicitly disabled with
>   BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS (Boost-wide disabling of threads) or
>   BOOST_POOL_NO_MT (this library only))  or for boost::mutex
>   (when threading support is enabled in the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

In boost/config/user.hpp:261 there is

```
//
// Turn threading support off if BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS is defined:
//
#if defined(BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS) && defined(BOOST_HAS_THREADS)
#  undef BOOST_HAS_THREADS
#endif
```

I think if you
    #define BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS
before including  it will solve it.
After you will have to manage this option into your build system for your users maybe.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the boost::pool dependency on thread lib was added in boost 1_48 (see [1.47](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/pool/detail/mutex.hpp) and [1.48](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/pool/detail/mutex.hpp)

I think this is unfortunate, a better decision it would have been to use the header only [lightweight mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/lightweight_mutex.hpp)

You can change the pool\detail\mutex.hpp but probably it is simpler to link with the thread lib, especially if you are using other libs.